# Ошибка api запроса react fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch

`введите сюда код`Посылаю запрос к серверу "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/#2PGYGGRJQ" через fetch таким образом:

```js
fetch("https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/#2PGYGGRJQ").then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

И кидает ошибку *fetch error*, а сам запрос не выполняется

Пробовал другие api протестировать и они работали. Сама ссылка рабочая и кидает json с ответом.

Api требует конечно некоторые заголовки авторизации, но и без них же должен отправлять хоть какой-то ответ

Comment: Как апи что-то ответит, если не авторизован?)) апи видимо и говорит что не авторизован ошибка)

Comment: Ну так если самому перейти через браузер, то он отправляет

Comment: Даже если вставить заголовки,то все равно ```fetch('https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/#2PGYGGRJQ',
       {
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImYyNjg1N2QxLTViMTAtNDM1MS05MmM2LTMxYTM4MTI4MjIzZCIsImlhdCI6MTY0NzUwNzg4OSwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL2IzMmJkNjAyLTY0MzctN', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }), 
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));```

Comment: А ошибку надо угадать?

Comment: Я сам её не вижу, можете сами протестировать

Comment: По вашему запросу с заголовками сервер отвечает со статусом 404. Вам нужно проверить документацию API. Скорее всего проблема в URL

Comment: Вообще запрос к API с решёткой выглядит ну очень подозрительно. Скорее всего вы где-то что-то неправильно прочитали

Comment: Текст с решёткой это тег. Я делал через encodeURIComponent и также